# What is the Javascript to find if a control is in the active RadPageView?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have one Telerik RadGrid inside of a RadPageView, and another RadGrid inside of another RadPageView. Both are part of the same RadMultiPage control. I am writing a Javascript function to resize the RadGrids to fill the remaining space in the window. How do I determine which RadGrid is the visible one in the active RadPageView?

This might give you a clearer idea of what I mean:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizeElements(sender, EventArgs) {
  var m_grid = sender;
  if(m_grid) {
     m_grid.GridDataDiv.style.height = right_pane_height - padding + "px";
  }
}
</script>
<div id="right_pane">
<telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" >
  <telerik:RadPageView runat="server">
     <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" >
       <ClientSettings>
           <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="resizeElements" />
         </ClientSettings>
     </telerik:RadGrid>
  </telerik:RadPageView>
  <telerik:RadPageView runat="server">
     <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" >
       <ClientSettings>
           <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="resizeElements" />
         </ClientSettings>
     </telerik:RadGrid>
  </telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Why dont you try setting some Ids on your telerik controls, then using jquery ID selector $("#id"), then check their styles. (telerik page view may have its own property to get set as active, not sure off the top of my head)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it is not necessary to know which RadGrid is visible in order to resize it. I simply resize both of them. The only catch is that I need to make sure that the RadGrid and it's GridDataDiv element exist, because they might not exist when the RadPageView they are on is not visible.

```
if( m_grid && m_grid.GridDataDiv ) {
      m_grid.GridDataDiv.style.height = right_pane_height - padding + "px";
}

if( m_grid2 && m_grid2.GridDataDiv ) {
      m_grid2.GridDataDiv.style.height = right_pane_height - padding + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Telerik, however, a generic approach would be to have a look at the classes of your elements in Firebug/Chrome F12 view/similar and then use JQuery to find the "div:visible" inside your RadMultiPage (give this an ID or a Class if you can in ASP.NET). Inside of this you will find your grid.

Your JQuery might look something like this:

```
$('#myMultiPageID > div:visible > .classOfRadGrid').each(function() {
    resizeElements(this, myEventArgsVariable);
});
```